# Override a style that I don't have access to

Tags: jquery, html, css, class, iframe

I am trying to override a style that is declared in a style sheet that I don't have access to. I am trying to remove height:auto on an iframe as its breaking and not working on android and mobile.

The iframe runs a booking system and has stages of variable height throughout so setting height value wouldn't work, I just need to override the auto height part.

```
.main iframe{width: 100%; height: auto !important;}
```

If I could somehow remove the height auto it would fix my problem, I just don't know how I could achieve this, I have tried using a line of jquery below, but this didn't work either.

```
$( "iframe" ).removeClass( "main iframe" );
```

Any help & advise would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: 1st: `.main iframe` doesn't mean the iframe has class `main` it means this is the element with class `.main` contains the iframe .. in this css iframe doesn't has a class .. so you need to use `.css('height' , 'newHeightpx')`

Comment: The `height` attribute in CSS defaults to `auto`. So if you "remove" or unset it, it's still going to be `auto`. The only way to make it not `auto` is to explicitly make it something else. So my question here is, what do you want it to be, other than "not `auto`"? Because if it's not something you articulate, it's going to be `auto`.

Comment: Basically I need to remove the auto declaration so the heights which are being sent via the booking form are used and not removed with the height auto class.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code, Hope it will work...

```
$( "iframe" ).prop('style','width: 100%;');
```

Comment: `height: unset` only resets the height to its default value of `auto`, so if the OP tries this, they will not notice any difference.

Comment: You are right, But if i remove height then it will be as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use **JavaScript/jQuery** to unset the height property.

You just need to add another style in your CSS that targets the iframe with a higher specificity like this:

```
// original style property
.main iframe{width: 100%; height: auto !important;}

// replace "body" with any parent element wrapping your ".main" element
// Change 20% to whatever new value you want to set for the element's height
body .main iframe{height: 20% !important;}
```

---

Check and run the **Code Snippet** below for a practical example of the above approach:

```css
/* CSS */
button {
   background-color: green !important; // old color
}
div button {
   background-color: red !important; // new color
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<div>
  <button>
    ABCD
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Andrew. I tried using unset, but it removes the height being sent from the booking form? My logic was trying to remove that iframe style completely from that page.

Comment: Check the updated answer. Instead of unsetting the height value, you can add your new desired height value to your iframe element instead.

Comment: % value won't work either Andrew, I originally tried 100% but had the same outcome and content was collapsed.

Comment: The 20% is just for example's sake. You can replace it with any value that you want the iframe height to be equal to. In other words, the above approach lets you override the !important tag as you initially wanted.

Comment: The issue is variable height on each of the process. Thanks Andrew,